# PHP process() function

Tags: php

I was doing some reading through the PHP manual and ended up on this page:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php

While reading example #2 I found an odd function being called that I have never seen before: `process()`

I looked all through the PHP manual site and could not find any documentation. From what I could understand from looking at the example it seems pass the strings as the first 2 arguments through an array of create_function()'s. Could anyone point me to some documentation on this? It seems like an interesting and possibly useful function. Examples of it effectively in use would be great too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of example #2, they are defining that function.

```
function process($var1, $var2, $farr)
{
    foreach ($farr as $f) {
        echo $f($var1, $var2) . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Heh, I hear you there.  No problem!